# How to fetch hasMany relationship data array inside controller?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

My model relation is defined as follows

```
App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
     name: DS.attr(),
     imageUrl: DS.attr(),
     bills: DS.hasMany("bill", { async: true}),
});

App.Bill = DS.Model.extend({
    description: DS.attr(),
    amount: DS.attr(),
    person: DS.belongsTo("person")
});
```

How to fetch bills of all persons inside controller and pass it to controller so that i can display all bills? 
One solution is to iterate inside the handlebars template. 
But i need to fetch the data in the controller itself and use them as property in template?

```
App.DashboardController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    bills: function(){
        return /*Bills here*/;
    }.property()
});
```

Comment: If you want _all_ bills for _all_ people, you're going to have to tell us what the model for the `DashboardController` is. You set the model in the `model` hook of `DashboardRoute`.

Comment: I am looking for person model in model hook of DashboardRoute

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, and the `App.Person` instance is the model of your `DashboardRotue`, then I'm not sure what you want is possible with what you have currently.

As a little background info, controllers in Ember.js *decorate* a model. In layman's terms, it means that all properties come from the controller, even if the controller has to ask the model for them. So if you asked your controller for the `bills` property, it would see that it didn't have one, and get the one from the model instead. So if all you wanted was the bills for that one person, you wouldn't need to declare anything in your controller at all. You could just do this in your template and it would work fine:

```
<ul>
    {{#each bills}}
        <li>{{amount}} - {{description}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

But if I understand you correctly, you seem to wants bills for *all* people. That is a little trickier, but still possible. If you wanted *all* of the bills in the whole system (which I think would be the same), the easiest way would be to fetch them all and use them as the model in an `ArrayController`.

```
model: function() {
    return this.store.find('bill'); // Find all bills
}
```

You template would then look like this:

```
<ul>
    {{#each}}
        <li>{{amount}} - {{description}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

But if you wanted to get the bills for *all* of the people, you have your work cut out for you. You would need do the same as above, only get all of the `person`s instead of the `bill`s. You would then need a computed property in your controller to join all of the bills for all of the people. But instead you can't nest `@each` observers, your property wouldn't update properly. If this is really your use case, I would strong suggest rethinking it. If you really need it, I can help you, but again, it won't be easy.